# Unable to "npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node"

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, npm, node-gyp

I'm trying to install Node.js bindings for tensorflow.js. However, when I run "npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node", I get the following output. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

```
D:\tensorflow.js>npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-node

> @tensorflow/tfjs-node@0.1.7 install D:\tensorflow.js\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\tensorflow.js\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node
"" rebuild )
gyp: Undefined variable tensorflow-library-target in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16299
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\tensorflow.js\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN tensorflow@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN tensorflow@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @tensorflow/tfjs-node@0.1.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @tensorflow/tfjs-node@0.1.7 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-23T18_50_36_025Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong, but you're using Windows but as I can see on the [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-node) – tfjs-node is available on Linux and macOS only.

> TensorFlow.js for Node currently supports the following platforms:
>
> 1. Mac OS X CPU (10.12.6 Siera or higher)
> 2. Linux CPU (Ubuntu 16.04 or higher)
> 3. Linux GPU (Ubuntu 16.04 or higher and Cuda 9.0 w/ CUDNN v7) (see installation instructions)

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Such a silly mistake. I was just following the Getting Started guide on js.tensorflow.org.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Comment: Now TensorFlow.js supports Windows (CPU only)

Answer (score 2):

Finally, i can run TensorFlow.js Node sample on Windows. Indeed, it runs on Ubuntu WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

1. Enable WSL with powershell and install Ubuntu WSL from Microsoft Store.
2. Install several tool in Ubuntu WSL by apt-get, including NodeJS, Make, G++. Because the warning message is vague, I nearly gave up.
3. optional: [Running Node.js on WSL from Visual Studio Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/10/27/running-node-js-on-wsl-from-visual-studio-code/)

I may missed some trivial steps.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make sure that you are using Python 2.7 and not Python3.*
The best option would be to create a new virtualEnv with python 2.7 and then do the installation.

Please refer: https://github.com/caisq/tfjs-node for more details!